# Can you solve this?

Tags: riddle, word

I have one, you have one.

If you remove the first letter, a bit remains.

If you remove the second, bit still remains.

After much trying, you might be able to remove the third one also, but it
 remains.

It dies hard!

Comment: It would be better if the title somehow related to the puzzle.  "Can you solve this" says absolutely nothing.

Comment: http://www.buzzle.com/articles/best-riddles.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it:

> Habit? Remove the first letter to get "abit", the second to get "bit", and the third to get "it". A habit may fit the clue "dies hard" but possibly some of these other words could also: http://crossword-solver.org/%3Fabit

Answer (score 3):

You are talking about

> the word **habit**

I have one, you have one.

> We all have our own habits.

If you remove the first letter, a bit remains.

> Removing the 'h', you get the letters 'abit'.

If you remove the second, bit still remains.

> Removing the second letter 'a', you get the letters 'bit'.

After much trying, you might be able to remove the third one also, but it remains.

> Removing the third letter 'b', you are left with 'it'.

It dies hard!

> It's a popular saying that habits die hard.